# Frequent 504 Gateway Time-out on appharbor

Tags: appharbor

Deployed an asp.net mvc 4 app on appharbor with very low traffic. Each time the application is accessed after deployment of after a few minutes of inactivity, I get a 504 gateway time out error from nginx. Very annoying, what can I do to work around the error?

EDIT:

[support ticket](http://support.appharbor.com/discussions/problems/21905-frequent-504-gateway-time-out) on appharbor's support site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP 504 is returned because the application doesn't respond within the request timeout. Application startup can take a little while, so sometimes a 504 may be returned on the initial request.

Applications on the free plan idle out after 20 minutes of inactivity. You can upgrade to one of the paid plans as they don't idle out after a period of inactivity.

We (AppHarbor) are working on decreasing the time it takes for applications to start up, which will mitigate the issue further. Note that the default request timeout was very recently increased to 120 seconds, so if you continue to experience this you're very welcome to open a ticket and let us know the application name so we can take a closer look.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'll file a ticket since the 504 is systematic and my app doesn't seem to do any heavy loading.